# Discord.py meme command takes a lot of time

Tags: discord, discord.py, praw, asyncpraw

I am making a bot in discord.py and have a fully working meme command using asyncpraw (praw did not work). But it takes a lot of time around 8-10 seconds for the meme to appear. Is there any way to reduce the time? Here is the code :-

```
@client.command(aliases=['memes'])
async def meme(ctx):
    subreddit = await reddit.subreddit("memes")
    all_subs = []
    top = subreddit.top(limit = 200)
    async for submission in top:
      
      all_subs.append(submission)
    
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    ups = random_sub.score
    link = random_sub.permalink
    comments = random_sub.num_comments
    embed = discord.Embed(title=name,url=f"https://reddit.com{link}", color=ctx.author.color)
    embed.set_image(url=url)
    embed.set_footer(text = f"{ups} {comments}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes a while because **everytime you execute the command, it'll always generate a list of submissions to pick from** but then the list just disappears after the command executes which means that *you generate 200 posts every command execution just to pick from one*

If you want a more efficient, faster way, make it a separate function!

```py
all_subs = []


async def gen_memes():
    subreddit = await reddit.subreddit("memes")
    top = subreddit.top(limit = 200)
    async for submission in top:
      all_subs.append(submission)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await gen_memes()  # generate memes when bot starts

@client.command(aliases=['memes'])
async def meme(ctx):
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    all_subs.remove(random_sub)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    ups = random_sub.score
    link = random_sub.permalink
    comments = random_sub.num_comments
    embed = discord.Embed(title=name,url=f"https://reddit.com{link}", color=ctx.author.color)
    embed.set_image(url=url)
    embed.set_footer(text = f"{ups} {comments}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
    if len(all_subs) <= 20:  # meme collection running out owo
        await gen_memes()
```

of course this is not the most efficient way, if you want to refill your memes in a certain interval, you can use [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)!